# How to show Price range in PHP?

Tags: php

Code:

```
$start = 8;
$end = 550;
$step = 100;

for($i=$start; $i<$end; $i=$i+$step){
    $firstNum = $i;
    $lastNum = $i + $step;
    echo $firstNum.' - '.$lastNum;
    echo "<br>";
}
```

Output:

```
8 - 108
108 - 208
208 - 308
308 - 408
408 - 508
508 - 608
```

I want to my output should be like-

```
8 - 100
101 - 200
201 - 300
301 - 400
401 - 500
501 - 600
```

How to do that in php code?

Comment: What is the purpose of `$step` here??

Answer (score 3, accepted):

While using a `$step = 100;` you have to round down both range ends to nearest multiple of `100` but with one incremental step, using a `if` condition will do the job:

```
for ($i = $start; $i <= ceil($end / $step) * $step; $i++){
    if ($i % $step == 0) {
        echo $start, " - ", $i, PHP_EOL;
        $start = $i + 1;
    }
}
```

Output:

```
8 - 100
101 - 200
201 - 300
301 - 400
401 - 500
501 - 600
```

Answer (score 4):

As per your requirement, you need a `do..while()` loop here. First time you need to initialize the `$firstNum` with the value of `$start` and then make a loop, assign the `$lastNum` by adding the `$step` into it. then echo or store the given values. after that you again need to assign the `$firstNum` by adding the 1.

You need something like this-

```
$start = 8;
$end = 500;
$step = 100;
$lastNum = 0;
$firstNum = $start;

do{    
    $lastNum += $step;
    echo $firstNum.' - '.$lastNum."<br/>";
    $firstNum = $lastNum+1;
}while($lastNum <= $end);
```

Comment: No logic in the loop. Good.

Answer (score 2):

With a little bit of math, you can calculate the number of iterations you need, then adding some small logic you can have the outcome you desire.

```
$start = 8;
$end = 550;
$step = 100;

$iteration = ceil($end / $step); //Calculate how many iterations we need

for($i=0;$i<$iteration;$i++) {
    $n = range(($i*$step), ($i*$step)+$step); //Build an array of numbers

    if($i == 0) { //If it's the first iteration, start at "8"
        echo $start .' - '. end($n) . PHP_EOL;
    } else {
        echo current($n) + 1 .' - '. end($n) . PHP_EOL;
    }

}
```

https://repl.it/DmhN

Comment: You just made made it more complicated than it is o.0

Answer (score 1):

Just change it a little bit like this:

```
$min = 8;
$end = 550;
$step = 100;

for($i=0; $i<$end; $i=$i+$step){
    //use $min only once as an exception in first iteration 
    //also added here "+ 1"
    $firstNum = max($min,$i+1); 
    $lastNum = $i + $step; 
    echo $firstNum.' - '.$lastNum;
    echo "\n";
}
```

Result:

```
8 - 100
101 - 200
201 - 300
301 - 400
401 - 500
501 - 600
```

https://3v4l.org/fr4ro

Answer (score 1):

Maybe like this:

```
<?php
$start = 8;
$end = 550;
$step = 100;
for($i=$start; $i<$end; $i=$i+$step){
   $firstNum = $i;
   $lastNum = $i + $step;
   $sp = $start - 1;
   if($i!=8) {
       $firstNum = $firstNum - $sp;
   }
   $lastNum = $lastNum - $start;
   echo $firstNum.' - '.$lastNum;
   echo "<br>";
}
?>
```

Answer (score -1):

TRy this:

```
for($i=$start; $i<$end; $i=$i+$step){
    $firstNum = $i + (($i==$start) ? 0 : 1);

    $lastNum = $i + (($i==$start) ? ($step - $start) : $step);
    $i = $lastNum-$step;

    echo $firstNum.' - '.$lastNum;
    echo "<br>";
}
```

Comment: where is the issue?

Answer (score -1):

Another take on the problem :-)

```
    for ($n = (int) ($start / $step); $n < (int) ($end / $step) + 1; $n++)
    {
        $left = $n * $step + 1;
        if ($start > $left)
            $left = $start;
        $right = ($n + 1) * $step;
        echo $left . ' - ' . $right;
        echo "<br>";
    }
```

Answer (score -3):

Make the loop start at `1`, put the resulting strings for each line in an array and then change the first line output afterwards with something like `str_replace()`. Then print the results in a 2nd loop, or with `implode()`.

```
$step  = 100;
$rows  = array();

for($i = 1; $i <= 6; $i++){
    $next = $i * $step;
    $rows[] = $next - ($step-1) .' - '. $next;
}

$rows[0][0] = 8;  // replace first letter in first line with "8"
echo implode("</br>", $rows);
```

There. No conditions and no function calls inside the loop, only maths.